# Having a little z-index trouble

Tags: css, layout, z-index, css-position

Trying to get the layout shown here http://www.reversl.net/zindex/ to look like the image attached [image] To clarfiy.....The logo (which is part of the header) needs to overlay the image. The image needs to align perfectly with the bottom of the header. I know this can be achieved using z-index but how exactly could I go about this?

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background: #222;
position: relative;
z-index: 3000;
}

#login {
width: 30%;
float: right;
text-align: right;
padding: .5em 0;
z-index: 5000;
}

#logo {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding: 3em 3em 1em 3em;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #222;
}

.logo-text {
font: 2em/1em "lucida grande";
display: inline-block;
color: #777;
}  

#bg {
margin: -2em 0 0 0;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Guess: Add to img style: margin-top:-logo_height px;z-index: 6000;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#login {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 5000;
}

#logo {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
    float: left;
    padding: 3em 3em 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 9999;
}


.wrap-inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1216px;
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Added to `#logo - postion: absolute,` and for  `.wrap-inner -  position: relative;`

and also padding removed of `#login`

Comment: Id use lower sequential z-index taking into account the design of the entire site but otherwise this is spot on Id say +1

Answer (score 4):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUVQK/)

What I always use is a `position: absolute` div inside a `position: relative` one.

Answer (score 2):

Is not about `z-index` is about `position`

```
.wrap-inner {
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 1216px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 95%;
}
```

[MDN explanation of absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)

> [...] an element that is positioned absolutely is **taken out of the flow** and thus **takes up no space** when placing other elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a specific solution how the z-index work, but in this specific example it could be a better approach:

You could loose the image as html element and rather set background image on body like this:

```css
body{
  background-image: url(http://www.reversl.net/zindex/bk.jpg);

  /* Set top position on background image 30px down (header height value): */
  background-position: 0px 30px;

  /* Also in CSS3 it is possible to set size: */
  background-size: 100% Auto;
}
```